# How can I use a Azure Database for PostgreSQL in a Azure Logic App?

Tags: azure-logic-apps, azure-database-postgresql

To simulate a device I want to use a Logic App to fill a Azure Database for PostgreSQL with test data.

I found the two connectors PostgreSQL and SQL server but unfortunately both don't work for me. The PostgreSQL connector does only support onpremise databases and neither the autodetection nor the manually input of the connectionstring works with SQL Server.

Would great if somebody could give me a hint how to write data into a Azure Database for PostgreSQL from a Logic app.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no connector available for this as of today.

The current alternatives would be

- Use [Azure Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-overview) (which can be [called from Logic Apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-azure-functions) if required)
- Create [Custom APIs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-create-api-app) and a [Custom Logic App Connector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/custom-connector-overview)

Also, there is a feature request on [UserVoice](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/287593-logic-apps/suggestions/36672061-add-trigger-and-connector-for-azure-postgre-sql) that you may upvote to gain traction.